# failure to Push to git repistory

Tags: git, repository, push

first of all: I am soory, I watched some questions that their subjects were familiar to my question  but I did not succeeded to solve my problem.

I open at github repository that her name is "Driving_School".
I want to push a c# project to this repository, but as you can see at the attached picture, I failed to push the project becuase "github.com/davyeu/Driving_School does not appear to be git repository".
Why he do not consider it as a git repository?

Thank for your help

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding your ssh key?

Comment: what is it ssh key?

Comment: Watch this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgZIv5HI44o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a wrong URL that lacks the protocol. To fix:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/davyeu/Driving_School.git
```